# Error: unused arguments using SMOTE

Tags: r

I'm trying to do oversampling with SMOTE in Rstudio. But not getting anywhere with my code because of the same error everytime! I hope that someone can help me with this:

```
trainSplit <- SMOTE(`hypothyroid, negative` ~ ., trainSplit, perc.over = 100, perc.under=200)
Error in SMOTE(`hypothyroid, negative` ~ ., trainSplit, perc.over = 100,  : 
  unused arguments (perc.over = 100, perc.under = 200)
```

all previous steps were no problem, but doesn't matter what i try with the SMOTE, always this same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be due to reading the smotefamily package vs SMOTE. If you read smotefamily SMOTE is masked and you cannot define perc.over and perc.under. Try to only load SMOTE and rerun the script

Comment: Smote from DMwR doesnt exist anymore, can you let me know any other way to deal with this?

Comment: Sorry, not using R atm so no clue, perhaps there is still an older version of the library available in the version history https://github.com/cran/DMwR/commits/master or a newer alternative library